# How can I test a Controller's protected method using reflectionClass in a unit test?

Tags: windows, docker, phpunit, phalcon

## Environment

- Windows10
- phalcon 3.2.4
- Docker for Windows 18.03.1-ce-win65
- phpunit 5.7.27

## Problem

I want to test my controller's private property using reflectionClass with phpunit, but I didn't manage to retrieve the data.

Using ReflectionClass, I should have cleared the problem of access rights, but I'm still receiving null for value.

I'd like to fix this issue and properly complete my unittest. Do you see what's wrong with my code ?

## test

In the process of uploading an excel file, I want to test the error contents when trying to upload a file without selecting a file.

## error message

```
Call to a member function getValue() on null
```

## code

- test file

```php
class StackOverFlowTest extends \UnitTestCase
{

    public function testsFileUploadError(){

        //StackOverFlowControllerのMockを作る
        $mockStackOverFlowController = $this->getMockBuilder(\App\Controllers\StackOverFlowController::class)
        ->setMethods(['runAction'])
        ->getMock();

        $mockStackOverFlowController->request = new class {

            public function hasFiles() 
            {
                return false;
            }
         };

            $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass('\Base\Controller');
    　　　　 $reflectionClass->getMethod('_setErrorContent')->setAccessible(true);
            $reflectionClass->getMethod('_formatKey')->setAccessible(true);
            $reflectionClass->getMethod('_setContent')->setAccessible(true);
            $reflectionClass->getproperty('_content')->setAccessible(true);

            $mockStackOverFlowController->runAction(1,1);

            $content = $reflectionClass->getMethod('_setContent')->setAccessible(true)->getproperty('_content')->getValue();

            $this->assertEquals(
                "select file",
                $content->_content,
                "file select error"
            );
        }
    }
```

- the controller that is actually moving（Only necessary parts）

```php
class StackOverflowController extends \Base\Controller
{

    public function runAction($firstId, $secondId)
    {
        // Check that file was uploaded.
        if (!$this->request->hasFiles()) {
            $this->_setErrorContent('Select file, 'snackbar');
        } else {
```

- BaseController extended.

After _setContent, go to the afterExecuteRoute method and pass it to view there

```php
class Controller extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    const ERRORS_RESPONSE_KEY = 'errors';
    protected $_content;

    protected function _setErrorContent($data, $key = null)
    {
        $key = $this->_formatKey($key);
        $this->_setContent($data, self::ERRORS_RESPONSE_KEY . $key);
    }

    private function _formatKey($key = null)
    {
        if (is_string($key) && !empty($key)) {
            return '.' . $key;
        } elseif (is_null($key)) {
            return '';
        }
        throw new \Exception('must specify response key', 500);
    }

    protected function _setContent($data, $keys)
    {
        $content = $this->_content;
        $temp = &$content;

        foreach (explode('.', $keys) as $key) {
            $temp = &$temp[$key];
        }

        $temp = is_array($temp) ? array_merge($temp, $data) : $data;
        $this->_content = $content;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This simply means there is no such property, are you sure you accessing proper one? Don't you need to use `_content`? You can't access variable in method body using reflection I think.

Comment: Thank you for your support! 
I changed the code from `$content` to `_content` in test file, but error message did not change(Call to a member function getValue() on null)

Comment: Maybe check first what `getProperties()` return?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved　by myself.
I can get private properties!

```
$propGetter = Closure::bind(function ($prop) {
        return $this->$prop;
    }, $class, $class);
    return $propGetter;
```

$class is mock of a Class.